# Why does SendMessageTimeout not take a DWORD?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to work with some C code that I have from an API (it doesn't like C++ compilers), but I am running into some trouble. I have this code:

```
// send the request (allow up to 9 tries)
while ((++i < 10) && !SendMessageTimeout(
        m_hWnd,       // FS6 window handle
        m_msg,        // our registered message id
        m_atom,       // wParam: name of file-mapping object
        0,            // lParam: offset of request into file-mapping obj
        SMTO_BLOCK,   // halt this thread until we get a response
        2000,             // time out interval
        &dwError))    // return value || dwError is a DWORD
{   Sleep(100); // Allow for things to happen
}
```

It returns an error (I am using Qt Creator):

```
error: C2664: 'LRESULT SendMessageTimeoutW(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM,UINT,UINT,PDWORD_PTR)' : cannot convert argument 7 from 'DWORD *' to 'PDWORD_PTR'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

I don't have experience working with DWORDs and PDWORD_PTRs, so I don't quite understand this. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need to see any more of the code, but I think this is all that is relevant.

Comment: `P<type>` in the winapi is `<type> *`. Use a `DWORD_PTR` instead of a `DWORD`. If you want to see what `DWORD_PTR` actually is, use [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dwError` needs to be a `DWORD_PTR`, not a `DWORD`.

Note that `DWORD_PTR` doesn't mean "a pointer to a DWORD", it means "a DWORD which is at least as big as a pointer".

Comment: Huh, I've always wondered why they were named like that, thanks.

Comment: I tried to use `PDWORD_PTR`, but that `DWORD_PTR` worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[PDWORD_PTR is a pointer to a DWORD_PTR.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)